# problem with the nginx config for a next js app on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

im trying to run a next js app on aws ec2 but when i visit the url of the server i get a 403 error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFF9Q.png the code for the app is in /var/www/kosher/ and im using pm2 to run the server, here is a screenshot of pm2 running, https://i.stack.imgur.com/V35Lf.jpg
and here are the nginx config files
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svmct.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qb2A.jpg

for reference im following this tutorial https://medium.com/today-i-solved/how-to-deploy-next-js-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-https-7980ec6fe8d3

i tested the app locally and it runs prefectly so i think the problem is with the nginx config, can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

never mind i fixed it by adding proxy pass and then localhost